# Is this the right statistical test?

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data

I'm designing a research plan (not actually performing it) and chose personality traits in internet addicts.

I decided to give my participants the Eysenck Personality Questionnaire(EPQ-R) in order to measure correlations of neuroticism extroversion, and psychoticism and set up three hypotheses.

Is it cronbach's alpha? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the test? According to [this page](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/faq/what-does-cronbachs-alpha-mean/), Cronbach's Alpha `is not a statistical test – it is a coefficient of reliability (or consistency).`

Comment: Cronbach's alpha is used for developing/validating instruments. If the EPQ-R is already validated, compute the respective scores as per the instrument's scoring instructions and then perform a simple t-test to assess differences.

Comment: Thanks Peter, all I want to know is correlation strength. Sorry, i'm new to statistics! Thanks Adam!

Answer (score 0):

Cronbach's alpha is a measure of the reliability of a test. It is related to the interitem correlations of the questions.

If you want to test the correlation of the three factors on the EPQ-R then you want to use the correlation of the factor scores.

There is a *lot* of literature already published on this (Google EPQR factor structure). Most of it is behind various paywalls, but if you are at a university, you may be able to get behind those paywalls - I was not able to do so from home. What you will want to find out is whether Eysenck et al. set up orthogonal or oblique factor structure. If the former, then you would strong suspect that correlations among the factors would be close to 0 - and your research would be rather problematic.

As for hypotheses, usually the null would be that the correlations = 0. However, if Eysenck set up an oblique factor structure, then you might have hypotheses that that the correlations in your population are the same as in some other population.